# How to calculate Gibbs free energy from pKa?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, energy, free-energy

Is it possible to calculate Gibbs free energy ($ΔG = -RT\ln K_\mathrm{eq}$) of an acid dissociation reaction using the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$? If so, how?

Comment: Are you trying to find Gibbs free energy of the reactants and products or just the change in Gibbs free energy from the reaction?

Comment: Just the change in Gibbs free energy from the reaction.

Answer (score 3):

To find the change in Gibbs free energy $\Delta G$ for the reaction of an acid, you can simply use $K_\mathrm{a}$ in the formula you gave in place of $K_\mathrm{eq}$ ($K_\mathrm{a}$ is an equilibrium constant).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the Gibbs Energy of the acid disassociation, then sure you can just use Ka. But if you want to find the Gibbs Energy for some other reaction involving the acid, you can’t.